# Error from logwatch while sending mail with ssmtp to SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, logwatch, ssmtp

I'm running a server on AWS (ubuntu) and I need outgoing email to be able to email log files.  To do this I'm using ssmtp and amazon's SES (Simple Email Service).

I have the email addresses verified and everything works fine when I run tests from the command line.  The email is sent and received as expected.

The problem I'm having is with `logwatch`. When it runs (both from cron and by me directly), I see the follow error:

```
sSMTP[6890]: 554 Transaction failed: User name is missing: 'root'.
```

I have `logwatch` set up with:

```
MailFrom = logs@mydomain.com
MailTo = logs@mydomain.com
```

Both verified emails with SES.

`ssmpt.conf` is set up with:

```
root=logs@mydomain.com
mailhub=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
#rewriteDomain=mydoman.com   # Having these uncommented doesn't help
#hostname=mydomain.com
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=XXXXX
AuthPass=XXXXX
AuthMethod=LOGIN
FromLineOverride=YES
```

`revaliases`:

```
root:logs@mydoman.com:email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
logs:logs@mydoman.com:email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
```

ssmpt works find if I send email through it as a test.

Does anyone know what is happening and why it thinks the user name is missing?  I can send email through ssmpt as 'root' without a issue.  It's just `logwatch` that is causing issues.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/496662/forcing-email-address-cron-is-sent-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figure this out.

Despite what a lot of "sites" on the internet say, you do not modify the logwatch.conf file:

```
/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf
```

Instead you need to copy this file to:

```
/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf
```

And make any changes there.

After I did this, everything works. Hopefully this will save someone else days of headache.

In retrospect, I did think it odd to be modifying a config file in `/usr/share`. I should have listened to my gut.