# Forcing email address cron is sent FROM

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssmtp

I'm running Ubuntu on AWS and am using their SES (Simple Email Service) and sSmtp to email logs since that is the only need for email on the server.

I have ssmtp sent up and everything works, except emails sent from cron jobs are being rejected due to the From: address.  SES requires that the From: and To: email addresses be verified, but the email sent from cron and just `root`, not `root@mydomain.com`.

Is there a way to set the full email address that cron uses as the From: address, or is there a way to get ssmtp to rewrite the From: when it is a just a name with no domain?

My ssmtp.conf looks like this:

```
root=logs@mydomain.com
mailhub=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
rewriteDomain=mydomain.com
hostname=mydomain.com
#UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=XXXX
AuthPass=XXXX
AuthMethod=LOGIN
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Thanks.

Comment: It answers one part of my question, but doesn't address the part about is ssmtp can be configured to deal with naked username.

Answer (score 3):

cron is using the `sendmail` command to send mails. Normally the mailserver is appending the domain so in your case ssmtp would need to to that.

I never used sSMTP before but it's sender rewriting seems pretty strange. I looked at the source code and there is a file `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`.

The example lists this:

```
# sSMTP aliases
#
# Format:       local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
```

In your case probably:

```
root:logs@mydomain.com:email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465
```

Comment: The revaliases seems to be used for the To: address.  I do have it set  up as you've suggested.

Comment: No, it is used for the FROM address. Try setting the FromLineOverride to NO.

Comment: For what ever reason, setting the FromLineOverride to NO causes SES to reject the emails.  I am not sure why, but I found this advice when first setting it up and it solved the problem.

Comment: This answer is correct: configuring `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` per @Sebastian's explanation, and setting `FromLineOverride=NO` in `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` results in the sent emails being accept by Amazon SES.

Answer (score 2):

As it doesn't seem to be possible to change the From: address that cron sends from in Ubuntu, I have found a hacky solution. It's probably not the best way, but it does seem to work.

When ssmtp is installed, it creates a link from `/usr/sbin/sendmail` to `/usr/sbin/ssmtp`. What I did was delete the link and created a sendmail file that contains the following:

```
sed "s/From: root /From: root@mydomain.com /" | /usr/sbin/ssmtp $*
```

Now any mail sent from `root` will get rewritten to `root@mydomain.com`